# Catalog price rule for associate products

Tags: magento

I am running a Magento site and i want to apply catalog price rule according to selected size by customer. i have enable attribute setting use in promotion for that attribute.

Now i have a configurable product and i want if customer add product with size 7 then give 60% off.

> I have created that condition but its now working.

**Condition** 
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
size is  7
[image]

**Action**

Apply

Discount Amount *

60.0000
Enable Discount to Subproducts

Apply

Discount Amount *

60.0000
Stop Further Rules Processing
  [image]

Comment: Can you add a printscreen for the rules?

Comment: @Tudor-RaduBarbu Please check updated question

Answer (score 0):

By Default Magento dont provide this feature for configurable associated products. If you want to make it work, you may need some extensions :

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple